# How to retrieve Page Layout Assignment for a profile using Tooling REST API?

Tags: api, salesforce, force.com, tooling

Using Force.com Tooling API(REST),How do I get the page layout-record type assignments for the given profile id?

Requesting with

/services/data/v36.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Name,+Metadata+From+Profile+where+Id='00eXX000000XXXX'+limit+1

responds with blank nodes for recordtypes etc.

Is it even possible to retrieve the full metadata of Profile object with Tooling API?

Answer (score 0):

In short term, the layout assignment information is listed in RecordType instead of Profile.

When you retrieve whole SObject Describe from this endpoint:

```
/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Account/Describe
```

The response have a "recordTypeInfos" section like this:

```
[
{available: true, defaultRecordTypeMapping: true, master: false, name: "Account Name 1", recordTypeId: "xxx", …},
{available: true, defaultRecordTypeMapping: false, master: false, name: "Account Name 2", recordTypeId: "xxx", …},
{available: true, defaultRecordTypeMapping: false, master: true, name: "Account Name 3", recordTypeId: "xxx", …}
]
```

For each recordTypeInfo, it contains a value called url:

```
url:{layout:"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts/YourRecordTypeId"}
```

If you send a GET request to this endpoint, in the response you will see the Layout Id in:

```
{id: YourLayoutId}
```

**So the mapping is already done by salesforce. That layout id reflects the layout assigned to the current user.**